# If statement getting passed over

Tags: c#, serial-port

The if statement in my code isn't working, it always goes straight to the else, I know for sure the value IS 255 but it still won't go to if, I even tried testing it in the else and it reported back that it IS 255 so I don't know why it keeps doing this, im just really confused now, can someone help?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    serialPort1.Open();
    string lastLine = string.Empty;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string tailValue = lastLine;
            lastLine = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            string line = lastLine;

            label1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                label1.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) || string.Equals(tailValue, line)
                    ? label1.Text
                    : $"{line}";
            }));

            if (label1.Text == "255")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(label1.Text);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
                Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
            }

            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? You may "know for sure", but seems there is room for disagreement...

Comment: BeginInvoke is asynchronous, meaning that there's a chance that it doesn't finish until the if statement is called. Try putting a sleep before your if statement for a few seconds. If that fixes it, then you need to wait on the begininvoke result until it finishes, or use Invoke (which should block if memory serves me correctly).

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that you are executing asynchronous code, but not waiting for the result to be calculated before trying to use it.

Here's the documentation for [BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Note the description:

> Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread that the
>   control's underlying handle was created on.

So when the call to `BeginInvoke` happens, the next statement (in your case it's the `if` statement) is executed without waiting for your Action to complete.

So what is the value of `label1` before you execute Action? (it's probably not 255)

One way of fixing this would be to use `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke` - you're already encasing this in Task.Run, so why are you trying to start another asynchronous call, especially for what looks like a simple calculation *that the very next method depends on*.

The reason `Invoke` works is because unlike `BeginInvoke`, it's a synchronous call. The calling thread blocks until `Invoke` finishes.